# Javascript: Enable High Accuracy Geolocation

Tags: javascript, django, html, geolocation

How can I improve the geolocation by adding in Enable High Accuracy property into the code? I am a beginner and still learning Javascript. I would be grateful if someone could help me with this. Thank you.

script.js

```
var pos;

var $demo;

var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 5000,
};

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, options);
  } else {
    $demo.text("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  pos = position;
  var { latitude, longitude } = pos.coords;
  $demo.html(`Latitude: ${latitude}<br>Longitude: ${longitude}`);
  $('#btn_submit').attr("disabled", null);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $demo = $("#demo");
  $('#btn_submit').on('click', function() {
    var data = pos.coords;
    data.csrfmiddlewaretoken = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
    $.post("/ajax/insert", data, function() {
      alert("Saved Data!");
    });
  });
});
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'ajax/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Your Location</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button type="button" id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" disabled>Submit</button>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Member
def insert(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        member = Member(latitude=request.POST['latitude'], longitude=request.POST['longitude'])
        member.save()
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'success'})
```

Comment: [read some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition#Example) - note the `options` variable and the content within

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to rely on myself. I tried to add the following code, would this be correct (I edited it in the code too). I am guessing a lot :
 var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 5000,
};

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, options);
  } else {
    $demo.text("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

Comment: Using the *enableHighAccuracy* option doesn't necessarily improve the accuracy.

Comment: How can I ensure that it does? I did a try a little demo site while researching and I found it is accurate to about 10meters +/-

Comment: Additional information should be in the question, not comments. *options* is the third argument, not the second.

Comment: Accuracy depends on where the device gets its location from and what the user allows your code access to. If it's based on IP address, it might be out by thousands of kilometres. If trilateration from mobile phone towers, maybe 50m. GPS might be 10m, but it depends on the device and availability of GPS signals (not much inside a building or tunnel).

Comment: That's true RobG. I plan to use this on mobile, so it should be ok I guess. I still don't know how to solve this as I have a showPosition function inside. I'm not sure if I need the success or error message too as I already have an if, else statement for the error checking.